# Error: There is no row at position 0 while uploading a excel file to database

Tags: c#, sql, excel

```
ufExcelFile.EnableViewState = false;
        //filePath = ufExcelFile.Value.ToString();
        filePath = Server.MapPath("~/");
        filePath = filePath + ufExcelFile.Value;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); /****error line*****/
            System.Data.DataTable dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dtExcel.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("CNIC", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("PhoneNumber", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("BatchNumber", typeof(string)) });

            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcel);
            }
            excel_con.Close();


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ExcelToDB";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CNIC", "CNIC");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumber");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BatchNumber", "BatchNumber");
                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 2700;
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcel);
                    con.Close();
                    count++;

                }
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        lblTotalExecutionTime.Visible = true;
        lblTotalExecutionTime.Text = "Total Execution Time: " + sw.Elapsed;
```

can any one tell why is not having any sheet or any row at position zero. thanks
in advance.when i put file path in windows explorer it get file not present error too.
i have tried same code in windows application its working fine but in my website it not working with the same excel file.

Comment: The call to `excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable` is not returning any rows but you are immediately referencing `Rows[0]`.

Comment: but why its not returning any thing to schema table ?

Comment: Jack A. i just found file is not getting copy exactly on server. on my local machine its 23kb while on server its 7kb. is there any solution to get it copy completely ???